# Slider disappears from GUI after being used

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider, matlab-figure, matlab-gui

I try to make a MATLAB GUI programmatically and face the problem that my **slider disappears after using it**. I isolated the problem to keep the code short. In this GUI I want to refresh the `plotmatrix` each time the slider is used (ignore the fact that the value of the slider is completely irrelevant to my program, as mentioned before I really wanted to keep the code clean that's why I also removed this functionality). Here's the code (you have to run it as function):

```
function StackOverflowQuestion_GUI()
    % clear memory
    close all; clc;

    % initialize figure
    f = figure;

    % create main axes
    AX_main = axes('Parent',f,...
        'Units','normalized','Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7]);

    % create slider
    uicontrol('Parent',f,...
        'Style','slider','Callback',{@sliderCallback,AX_main},...
        'Units','normalized','Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.05]);

    plotmatrix(AX_main,randn(500,3));
    title('Random Plotmatrix');
end

function sliderCallback(~,~,AX_main)   % callback for slider
    plotmatrix(AX_main,randn(500,3));
    title('Random Plotmatrix NEW');
end
```

Any help is appreciated! I think I misunderstood the concept of AXES. When I plot to the AXES-handle I created, why are other parts of the figure affected as well? If someone could explain to me how this graphic-handle system basically works that would be very nice too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `plotmatrix`, the function completely redraws the figure,
to conserve other elements you should use `hold on;` `hold off;` statements:

```
function StackOverflowQuestion_GUI()
    % clear memory
    clear; close all; clc;

    % initialize figure
    f = figure;

    % create main axes
    AX_main = axes('Parent',f,...
        'Units','normalized','Position',[.1 .2 .8 .7]);

    % create slider
    uicontrol('Parent',f,...
        'Style','slider','Callback',{@sliderCallback,AX_main},...
        'Units','normalized','Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.05]);

    plotmatrix(AX_main,randn(500,3));
    title('Random Plotmatrix');
end

function sliderCallback(~,~,AX_main)   % callback for slider
    hold on;
    plotmatrix(AX_main,randn(500,3));
    hold off;
    title('Random Plotmatrix NEW');
end
```

Answer (score 6):

While [daren shan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003910/2748311) is correct, it's bizarre enough behavior that I was curious to see what is behind it.

Stepping through the source of [`plotmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotmatrix.html) we can find the line that deletes our slider object:

```
% Create/find BigAx and make it invisible
BigAx = newplot(cax);
```

Nothing obvious here, what does [`newplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/newplot.html) do?

> Use `newplot` at the beginning of high-level graphics code to determine
>   which figure and axes to target for graphics output. Calling `newplot`
>   can change the current figure and current axes. Basically, there are
>   three options when you are drawing graphics in existing figures and
>   axes:
>
> - Add the new graphics without changing any properties or deleting any objects.
> - Delete all existing objects whose handles are not hidden before drawing the new objects.
> - Delete all existing objects regardless of whether or not their handles are hidden, and reset most properties to their defaults before
>     drawing the new objects (refer to the following table for specific
>     information).

Oh...

So `newplot` is deleting the slider object.

---

So why does [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) prevent the slider from being deleted, despite it being an axis method and not a figure method? To start, take a look at the "Algorithms" topic in the documentation:

> The `hold` function sets the `NextPlot` property of the `Axes` or `PolarAxes`
>   object to either `'add'` or `'replace'`.

So `hold on` sets this to `'add'` for the current axes. However, for a reason I can't currently figure out, this *also* sets the `NextPlot` of the figure to `add` as well.

We can see this with a short snippet:

```
f = figure('NextPlot', 'replacechildren'); 
ax = axes; 
fprintf('NextPlot Status, base:\nFig: %s, Ax(1): %s\n\n', f.NextPlot, ax.NextPlot)
hold on
fprintf('NextPlot Status, hold on:\nFig: %s, Ax(1): %s\n\n', f.NextPlot, ax.NextPlot)
```

Which prints:

```
NextPlot Status, base:
Fig: replacechildren, Ax(1): replace

NextPlot Status, hold on:
Fig: add, Ax(1): add
```

Weird behavior, but I won't dwell on that.

---

Why does this matter? Go back to the `newplot` documentation. First, `newplot` reads the figure's `NextPlot` property to determine what to do. By default, a figure's `NextPlot` property is set to `'add'`, so it would retain all of the present graphics objects but `plotmatrix` explicitly changes this:

```
if ~hold_state
    set(fig,'NextPlot','replacechildren')
end
```

So `newplot` goes from:

> Draw to the current figure without clearing any graphics objects already present.

To:

> Remove all child objects whose `HandleVisibility` property is set to `on`
>   and reset figure `NextPlot` property to `add`.
>
> This clears the current figure and is equivalent to issuing the `clf`
>   command.

Which explains why the slider disappears and why `hold on` fixes the problem.

---

Per the documentation for `newplot` we can also set the `HandleVisibility` of the slider UIcontrol to save it from being destroyed:

```
% create slider
uicontrol('Parent',f,...
    'Style','slider','Callback',{@sliderCallback,AX_main},...
    'Units','normalized','Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.05], ...
    'HandleVisibility', 'off');
```

Comment: Wow, very nice researched! Thank you for that! Both solutions worked for me (when I put `hold` around the `plotmatrix` command or when I set `HandleVisibility` off). Thx!

Comment: tnx, great job :) and i could add this: from matlab doc: "hold on" sets the NextPlot property of the current "figure" and "axes" to add.

Comment: @darenshan no, the documentation explicitly states that it sets the `NextPlot` property of the *current axes*, which is not the figure. Setting `hold off` does not set the figure's `NextPlot` to `'replace'` like it does the axes.

Comment: @excaza see my post for previous version of matlab doc,